# Laravel redirecting problem when submitting form

Tags: laravel, forms, csrf

I have the following routes:

```php
Route::get('videos/{video}/edit', 'VideoController@edit');
Route::put('videos/{video}/update2', 'VideoController@update2');
```

The first route loads the following stripped view:

```php
<form action='/videos/{{$video->uid}}/update2' method='post'>
    <button class='btn btn-default' type='submit'>Update</button>
    {{csrf_field()}}
    {{method_field('PUT')}}
</form>
```

It is returned from the controller code of which is listed below:

```php
class VideoController extends Controller {
    public function edit(\App\Models\Video $video){
        return view('video.edit',[
            'video' => $video,
        ]);
    }
    public function update2(VideoUpdateRequest $request,\App\Models\Video $video){
        echo "ok";
    }
}
```

According to this code, expected behavior should be to see "ok", instead of that I get HTTP 302 Redirect, as shown below in the Dev Console.

[image]

This is a weird behavior, which is not expected. How to get the expected behavior of displaying "OK" after submitting the form?  How to debug this?

---

## SOLVED

The problem was with HTML elements in the form not having `name` attribute, thus Laravel Form Request Validation redirected back. After adding those missing attributes, form works as expected.

Comment: You need to redirect to a view and then send the success message to the view. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redirects. Either redirect back to the same page, or just plain view of "ok".

Comment: Thanks for the reply , issue is with validation,  when removing validation, route works as expected.

Comment: Please post your solution in an answer of its own, thank you.

Comment: answer added, Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLVED

The problem was that the elements in the HTML form did not have the `name` attribute, thus causing Laravel Form Request Validation to redirect back. After adding the missing attributes, the form works as expected.